# hiding xml from public direct access

Tags: xml

so my question is how do i prevent public access to an xml file on my server..

i have a website which allows users to listen to music online but you can't download... the music is in a flash player reading off an xml file..

the playlist for example will be named playlist.xml

how do i prevent the public to directly accessing the xml file if found via "view source" ?

is this possible if so how do i change settings?

Comment: You can: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/hide-web-xml-file-from-public-view

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The Flash client, running on the user's computer, has to be able to access the file. If it can access the file, then anything else running on the user's computer can too.

You could try adding in extra required HTTP headers (by editing the Flash player) but that is not difficult to bypass.

Comment: as i thought! so what could you explain more into http headers (extra ones) i mean obv a web guru would know where to look straight away but normal novice users will get confused....

how would you do this?

Comment: The flash player would send `X-Useless-Security: 1` and the server would return a `403` error if it wasn't present. Then the person trying to download the music would ask how to bypass it, and someone would spend five minutes investigating and then tell them in order to show off.

Comment: lol @ show off!
do you have a script for such http headers where i can use and just edit to my relevant needs please?

Comment: No. I don't do Flash, and I've no idea what server side environment you use.